# Where to ask questions about animation/Flash?

Tags: discussion, support, site-recommendation

I have a question about Flash, a tool used for animation. However, I don't know where to ask it!

- [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com)

  - The question is not about programming. (You can program in Flash but in this case I am not.)
- [Super User](http://superuser.com)

  - My question is about animation, not about computers/the software in general.
- [Game Development](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com)

  - I am making this animation for a game, but I think that's a bit of a stretch.
- [Graphic Design](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/)

  - The question is about Flash and animation, not the graphics.

So, where should I ask it?

Here is roughly what the question would look like:

> How can I tween to a previous frame in Flash?
>
> I have placed some movie clips on a frame, and added tweens to them. I
>   then created new keyframes later in the timeline, and I moved the
>   movie clips around and rotated them. Now, how can I get back to the
>   first frame's movie clip setup in a later frame?
>
> If I go to the first frame and try copying and pasting to the later
>   frame, Flash thinks I want to create entirely new tweens.

Comment: What aspect of animation in flash?

Comment: @Oded It is a question about tweens

Comment: [Stack Overflow has 149 timeline tween questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=flash+timeline+tween), [Game Development has 5](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/search?q=flash+timeline+tween), [Graphic Design has 3](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/search?q=flash+timeline+tween).

Comment: What would your question actually be? Exact text. It depends on where it would better fit. Don't be vague

Comment: @random edited.

Comment: So, your question is regarding authoring on the timeline?

Comment: @JasonSturges Umm, I have never heard the term "authoring on the timeline" before but yes, I suppose it is

Comment: There are questions like: [Flash UI, how to drag symbol with tween](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4410921/flash-ui-how-to-drag-symbol-with-tween/4435504#4435504) or [Operating on Multiple Layers in Flash CS6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13907829/operating-on-multiple-layers-in-flash-cs6)

Comment: @JasonSturges ...from 2010. It might not be accepted now.

Comment: I like [ToddBFisher's comment on that question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13907829/operating-on-multiple-layers-in-flash-cs6#comment19167457_13907829): _From what I've seen, you either work with the limitations of editing things from the timeline, or you go the developer route and get absolute power! Muahahaha! ... If going the programming route I recommend greensock.com/timelinemax for any timeline type of animations_

Comment: Any animation based Adobe multimedia authoring questions seem a poor fit Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: Forget timeline animations, GreenSock rocks! Anyway, timeline is pretty well explained in Adobe Docs... I don't work with Flash anymore, but actionscript.org forums was my first stop.

Answer (score 3):

How is it not on topic for [Graphic Design](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com)? It has an [adobe-flash](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adobe-flash) tag, and it's stated in the [FAQ](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/faq) that Flash animation is one of the permitted topics (being an example of digital media):

> - Digital media
>     Examples: video, Adobe Flash

I can't find anything on their meta that explicitly disallows questions about Flash. Or any form of 2D animation for that matter.

Comment: Do not ask: `Technical questions related to video editing software` (from the FAQ)

Comment: @Doorknob: The Flash IDE is not video editing software.

Comment: I'm not using it as an IDE. I'm using it to make an animation (video).

Comment: @Doorknob: Adobe Flash is often affectionately called "the Flash IDE", sorry for the confusion. But it's still not video editing software - I still don't see how a question about animating in Flash would be off limits there. Perhaps the term "technical questions" needs some clarification as well.

Comment: What are they even talking about? http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/3/should-this-se-site-include-technical-questions-ie-photoshop-etc